# How to send XML with attachments in Postman

Tags: xml, soap, multipartform-data, postman

I have a situation where i am trying to run a SOAP service request containing both attachments and a content body using postman but unable to find correct way to send it

Format is as below

Files to be uploaded are on my local machine.
file1 = //file.txt, file2 = //file.pdf

The keys of these files (file1 and file2) need to go as values in the xml body as below.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
 <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <sas:UploadRequest>
   <Param1>file1</Param1>
   <Param2>file2</Param2>
  </sas:UploadRequest>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```